# How to show full route in google static map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to show route a between two place on a google static map but when distance between two places image show like this:- [image: images show like that]

I want to show both point. How to do programmatically zoom out properly.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can define a viewport of the static map using a visible parameter. 
Please refer to the documentation for further details:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Viewports

Comment: I had the same problem, this is what i did:   1. I added the lats,and the longs then averaged to get the midpoint. 2. Then i calculated the distance between the two points 3.then i used trail method to create an optimum zoom level based on the distance between.so i had a switch statement to select a zoom level based on the distance between points.then i applied the camera zoom on the aveaged point

Comment: @PeterMushirih can you give me some example or explain some more.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are drawing your path using a polyline like this

So i added the function to calculate distance

```
 private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,List<List<HashMap<String,String>>>>{
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> routes=null;

        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
            try {
                jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                PathJsonParser pathJsonParser=new PathJsonParser();
                routes=pathJsonParser.parse(jsonObject);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> lists) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;
        if(routes.size()>0){
            // traversing through routes
            for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {

                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    points.add(position);
                }

                polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
                polyLineOptions.width(10);
                polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            }
        }
            if(null!=polyLineOptions) {
                mMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
                float totalDistance = 0;
                for(int k = 1; k < polyLineOptions.getPoints().size(); k++) {
                    Location currLocation = new Location("this");
                    currLocation.setLatitude(polyLineOptions.getPoints().get(k).latitude);
                    currLocation.setLongitude(polyLineOptions.getPoints().get(k).longitude);
                    Location lastLocation = new Location("that");
                    lastLocation.setLatitude(polyLineOptions.getPoints().get(k-1).latitude);
                    lastLocation.setLongitude(polyLineOptions.getPoints().get(k-1).longitude);
                    totalDistance += lastLocation.distanceTo(currLocation);
                }
                DISTANCE_BETWEEN= (int) (totalDistance/1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

So now i zoom out based on the distance between,and i zoom out from the mid point of both points like this

```
            LatLng x = new LatLng((LOCATION_FROM.latitude + LOCATION_TO.latitude) / 2, (LOCATION_FROM.longitude + LOCATION_TO.longitude) / 2);
            mMap.resetMinMaxZoomPreference();
            if (DISTANCE_BETWEEN < 30) {
                CAMERA_ZOOM = 8;
            } else if (DISTANCE_BETWEEN > 30 && DISTANCE_BETWEEN < 60) {
                CAMERA_ZOOM = 6;
            } else {
                CAMERA_ZOOM = 4;
            }
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(x, CAMERA_ZOOM);
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```